# XML Schema into Pathfinder Office to create a Data Dictionary?

Tags: xml, pathfinder

I have an exported XML Schema from a client database that I need to convert to a ASCII File in order to import the schema into the data dictionary editor in Pathfinder Office.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Pathfinder/TerraSync data dictionaries are not stored as plain text.  I've never heard of an automated way to convert XML to .ddf.  The only way I can think of is to build the data dictionary manually using the Pathfinder Office tool.